# GSAP multiple scroll triggers for lottie animations in different sections

Tags: javascript, gsap, lottie, scrolltrigger

I am trying to setup multiple gsap scroll triggers with lottie animations in 3 sections. I would like the screen to pin to the animations until they complete. This is the code I currently have, which seems to mostly work. I randomly will see issues where section scroll weird or animations don't finish completely. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<section class="section--01 section--side-by-side">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-center">
        <div class="cell medium-6">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cell medium-6 side-by-side-wrapper">
        <div id="section-lottie--01">
          <div class="lottie-container"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section--02">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-center">
        <div class="cell small-12 medium-6">
        <h2 class="text-center">Title</h2>
        <div id="section-lottie--02">
          <div class="lottie-container"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section--03 section--side-by-side">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-center">
        <div class="cell medium-6">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cell medium-6">
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
        <div id="section-lottie--03">
          <div class="lottie-container"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-f8mwTB+Bs8a5c46DEm7HQLcJuHMBaH/UFlcgyetMqqkvTcYg4g5VXsYR71b3qC82lZytjNYvBj2pf0VekA9/FQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.7.8/lottie.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  let mobile = window.innerWidth < 749;

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  LottieScrollTrigger({
    target: "#section-lottie--01 .lottie-container",
    trigger: ".section--01",
    path:'/jobseeker-bar-chart.json',
    speed: "medium",
    pin: ".section--01",
    scrub: 1,
    start: mobile ? "center 45%" : "center center"
  });

  LottieScrollTrigger({
    target: "#section-lottie--02 .lottie-container",
    trigger: ".section--02",
    path:'/salary-bar-chart.json',
    speed: "medium",
    pin: ".section--02",
    scrub: 1,
    start: "center 75%"
  });

  LottieScrollTrigger({
    target: "#section-lottie--03 .lottie-container",
    trigger: ".section--03",
    path:'/salary-scatter-chart.json',
    speed: "medium",
    pin: ".section--03",
    scrub: 1,
    start: mobile ? "center 45%" : "center 55%"
  });

  function LottieScrollTrigger(vars) {
    let playhead = {frame: 0},
      speeds = {slow: "+=2000", medium: "+=1000", fast: "+=500"},
      target = gsap.utils.toArray(vars.target)[0]
      st = {trigger: target, pin: true, start: "center center", end: speeds[vars.speed] || "+=1000", scrub: 1},
      animation = lottie.loadAnimation({
        container: target,
        renderer: vars.renderer || "svg",
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        path: vars.path
      });

    for (let p in vars) { // let users override the ScrollTrigger defaults
      st[p] = vars[p];
    }

    animation.addEventListener("DOMLoaded", function () {
      gsap.to(playhead, {
        frame: animation.totalFrames - 1,
        ease: "none",
        onUpdate: () => animation.goToAndStop(playhead.frame, true),
        scrollTrigger: st
      });
    });
  }
});

</script>
```

It seems that I get different results when I refresh the page. Randomly the page will jump to the next section while scrolling through an animation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have multiple scroll triggers, make sure the order of the scroll triggers that they are not conflicting with each other.

also possible that there are issues with the Lottie animations themselves